# How to change the order of variables which was ordered by alphabetically in ggplot graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I have the data named 'summarized',

[image]

if I make a bar graph using the below code

```
ggplot (data=summarized , aes(x=Stage, y=mean, fill=heat)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width = 0.5) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= mean-se, ymax=mean + se), position=position_dodge(0.5) ,width=0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c ("darkslategray","azure3"), name="Treatment")
```

The graph is like this, but I want Pre-Anthesis to comes first. How can I change this order?

Many thansk,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
summarized %>%
  mutate(Stage=factor(Stage,levels = c('Pre-Anthesis','Post-Anthesis'),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Stage, y=mean, fill=heat)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width = 0.5) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= mean-se, ymax=mean + se), position=position_dodge(0.5) ,width=0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c ("darkslategray","azure3"), name="Treatment")
```

You can also try directly in `ggplot2` function `scale_x_discrete()`:

```
#Code2
ggplot (data=summarized , aes(x=Stage, y=mean, fill=heat)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width = 0.5) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= mean-se, ymax=mean + se), position=position_dodge(0.5) ,width=0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c ("darkslategray","azure3"), name="Treatment")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c('Pre-Anthesis','Post-Anthesis'))
```

Output(in both cases):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Duck. Your code totally works!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You can also use `fct_relevel` from the `forcats` package to reorder the factor levels in the `State` variable. Something like `mutate(State = fct_relevel(State, c("Pre-Anthesis", "Post-Anthesis")`